# Download CSV file Using Spring MVC and OpenCSV jar

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to download a .csv file on clicking the Download button in my jsp.The jsp code is like following......

```
    <form:form method="POST" id="poCSVForm"
        action="downloadPoCsv" commandName="poCSVcmd" modelAttribute="poCSVcmd">

        <div class="content">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Page Name</legend>
                <div>
                    <div class="contentpane">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                    <td><button type="submit" value="Download" id="downId" class="dwnldbtn">Download</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="exit smallbtn" value="Exit">Exit</button></td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

Then my controller code is like this......

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadPoCsv", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doPoCsvDownload(
        @ModelAttribute("poCSVcmd") PurchaseOrderCSVBean poCsvBean,
        Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
     CSVWriter writer = null;
     String filepath = null;
    try {

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        Session hsession = (Session) session
                .getAttribute(MOLConstants.HIBERNATE_SESSION_KEY);
        filepath = "purchaseOrder" + new Date().getTime() + ".csv";

        ServletContext context = req.getServletContext();
        String realPath = context.getRealPath("");
        System.out.println("appPath = " + realPath);
        // construct the complete absolute path of the file
        String fullPath = realPath + "\\stuff\\" + filepath;

        System.out.println("fullPath = " + fullPath);

        File downloadFile = new File(realPath);
        try {
            if (!downloadFile.exists()) {
                if (downloadFile.mkdir()) {
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Could not create directory");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }           

        String mimeType = context.getMimeType(fullPath);   // get MIME type of the file
        if (mimeType == null) {

        mimeType = "application/octet-stream";  // set to binary type if MIME mapping not found
        }
        System.out.println("MIME type: " + mimeType);

        // set content attributes for the response
        response.setContentType(mimeType);
        response.setContentLength((int) downloadFile.length());

        // set headers for the response
        String headerKey = "Content-Disposition";
        String headerValue = String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"",downloadFile.getName());
        response.setHeader(headerKey, headerValue);

        List<PoCsvUploadView> csvDataList = poService.getPoCsvData(poCsvBean.getExp_ind(),poCsvBean.getStdt(),poCsvBean.getEnddt());

        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter(fullPath);
        writer = new CSVWriter(fwriter, ',', CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);

        String[] header = new String[31];

        header[0] = "COMPANY_CD";
        .......
        header[30] = "VENDOR_TYPE";

        List<String[]> li = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        li.add(header);

        for (PoCsvUploadView group : csvDataList)
        {
            String[] arr = new String[31];

            arr[0] = group.getCompany_cd();
            .....
            arr[30] = group.getVendor_type();
            li.add(arr);

        }
        writer.writeAll(li);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("Exception >> ", e);
        throw new CustomGenericException(
                "Error occured while loading report!!");
    }finally{
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Now When I am click on the download button, the csv file is being generated at the specific location ie on fullPath variable. But that file is not downloading through the browser, instead of that browser is downloading some file named downloadPoCsv(which is exactly same as my @RequestMapping in my controller method), which is not desired. Can you guys provides some help on this. Thanx in advance.And yes I am using OpenCsv jar.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear here the issue is spring MVC not openCSV because your problem description is that you are trying to download a file and it is downloading a file with a different name.

CodeJava has a [pretty good example of a Spring MVC download](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-sample-application-for-downloading-files).  Give that a try.